# How to change the Button content as CamelCasing in Windows phone 8.1 Message dialog

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, messagedialog

How to change the Button content as CamelCasing in Windows phone 8.1 Message dialog?

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("Do you want to continue?");
        msg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Ok", (command) => { }));
        msg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Cancel", (command) => { }));
        await msg.ShowAsync();           
    }
```

[image]

I want to change the ok as Ok and cancel as Cancel.

Comment: you can create Custom MessageBox. @Sankarann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a custom dialog you need to use a different control. The MessageDialog always lower cases the buttons to match the system style and is not generally customizable.

If you use a ContentDialog you can customize it fairly extensively, and it doesn't try to fix the case of its buttons. You'll probably want to create your own ContentDialog class (there's a template under Add.New Item...) with your desired contents, but here's a quick content-free example:

```
ContentDialog cd = new ContentDialog();
cd.Title = "My Title";
cd.PrimaryButtonText = "CoNtInUe";
cd.SecondaryButtonText = "sToP";
await cd.ShowAsync();
```

Also note that the [guidelines for message dialogs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738363.aspx) suggest using clear and specific verbs rather than generic OK/Cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Use Content Dialog box like this:

Add this code inside your xaml.

```
    <ContentDialog x:Name="AlertMessage" Background="#363636" IsSecondaryButtonEnabled="True" SecondaryButtonText="Cancel"  IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="True" PrimaryButtonText="Ok" >
        <ContentDialog.Content>
            <StackPanel Name="rootStackPanel" Height="Auto"  >
                <StackPanel Margin="0">
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="HeadingText" x:FieldModifier="public" Style="{StaticResource ApplicationMessageBoxHeadingStyle}" Text="Alert"  />
                        <Image Margin="10,05,0,0" Source="/Assets/Images/alert.png" Width="35"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="ContentText" Style="{StaticResource ApplicationMessageBoxErrorStyle}" Text="Are you sure you want to log off ?" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </ContentDialog.Content>
    </ContentDialog>
```

And call this like that in your code:

```
    private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox();
    }
    private async void MessageBox()
    {
        ContentDialogResult LogoutDialog = await AlertMessage.ShowAsync();

        if (LogoutDialog == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
        {
            // User pressed Ok.
        }
        else
        {
            // User pressed Cancel or the back arrow.
            // Terms of use were not accepted.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code:

```
 CustomMessageBox messagebox = new CustomMessageBox()
 {
      Caption = "Do you want to continue?",
      LeftButtonContent = "Ok",
      RightButtonContent = "Cancel"
 };
```

Comment: Is available in Wp 8.1 Store apps(winrt)?

Comment: I think it would be, I have used this in "Windows Phone Silverlight". You try it. It contains "Micosoft.Phone.Controls", so it is available. @Sankarann